Desert high school kid whose mother tried to send him to rehab in Fiji or Samoa
An Independent movie.  Time frame was maybe 2008 (a guess) – very modern – could be today. The location was the American Southwest desert, I think Vegas or Arizona
The kid was brilliant.  Lived in a desert suburb.  His mother was a mess, neurotic and concerned her son was wrecking his life with drugs. (and he was.)  She did an intervention.  Kid escapes (multiple times) - including faking to be sick and then escaping from the hospital bed before being sent to Fiji with a universal handcuff key he stitched into his shorts.
I believe, the main actor was the writer/director, and the story was actually based on his life.  I think.  (That's why I'm trying to find him and see if he's done anything since.)  I can’t remember that kid’s name or the movie – and it’s killing me I can’t find it via Google-Bing.

Voting to reopen as an answer appears to be available.

Now question is open and you can self-answer it or @user6045 can answer it. So i am roll-backing your last edit.

Drats.  user6045 was so kind to send me the answer some months ago (bravo) – via email – and I thought I edited the info into this, but now I've lost the email/info (#*%&@).  Apparently super users have access to prior edits – is the movie name in there?  Answer it, or let me answer it, and let's close this out.  Thanks.

@ipso: Ever have any luck finding that answer?

@#&#$ - just found the link to prior edits.  I'll answer it now.  @#$&#$#*&  Someone please edit out all these lame comments... ???  thanks.

Self Medicated (2005):

Based on true events. On the edges of Las Vegas, 17-year-old Andrew's
  life is spiraling out of control. Unable to cope with the loss of his
  father, Andrew's descent into drugs and violence is gaining momentum,
  and the once promising young man is now headed for self-destruction.
  Andrew's mother, helpless to control her son and fighting an addiction
  of her own, refuses to watch idly as her only child destroys himself.
  As a last resort, she hires a private company to forcibly kidnap and
  confine him in a locked-down and corrupt psychiatric hospital. As
  Andrew is subjected to the secret physical and emotional abuses of the
  program something inside him is re-awakened. He must somehow get free
  to save what's left of his life, but to do that, he knows he must
  first face his own demons head-on.

Director Monty Lapica.
